# Return all the cells that contain a certain word

Tags: google-sheets

I have a list of keywords, and I want to return the ones with specific words in them.

## Column A(List of Keywords)

```
twitter login    
twitter stock    
twitter logo    
twitter stock price    
facebook login    
facebook app    
facebook stock    
facebook en español    
facebook logo
```

## Column B(List of search keywords)

```
login
stock
logo
```

Beyond column C, I want to return *all the words from Column A, that contain the words from Column B.

So for keyword "login," I would have "twitter login" and "facebook login" in columns C-D. For keyword "stock," I would have "twitter stock" "twitter stock price" "facebook stock" in columns C-E. And so on.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found it,
Put in cell C1

```
=transpose(Query($A$1:$A,"select A where A contains '"&B1&"'"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula:

`=FILTER(A:A,REGEXMATCH(A:A,JOIN("|",B1:B3)))`

[image]

The result is list from Column A, that contain the words from Column B:

```
twitter login
twitter stock
twitter logo
twitter stock price
facebook login
facebook stock
facebook logo
```

Comment: What does the " | " mean?

Comment: | means "OR" in regex